# jQuery DataTables: How do I add a row ID to each dynamically added row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**Summary**

I am using the great dataTables jQuery plugin from http://www.datatables.net.  In my script, I am dynamically adding rows based on an event firing using `fnAddData`.  Using `fnRowCallback`, I add in a unique row ID.  This sometimes fails and does not add a row ID.  In a test of 46 row additions, usually 6 to 8 rows do not get a row ID.

**Add Row function**

```
function ps_ins(row)
{
  var rowArray = row.split('|');
  row = rowArray;
  var alarmID = parseInt(row[1],10);

  $('#mimicTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
    alarmID, 'col2', 'col3', 'col4',
    'col5', 'col6', 'col7'
  ]);
}
```

Rows are added to the table correctly.  The test I am running adds 46 rows, and all appear as expected.

**Add the row ID**

I am trying to add a unique ID to each row so I can later modify a specific row and refer to it in dataTable's cache using a combination of fnGetRows and .filter.

I am doing this using fnRowCallback during the initialisation stage.  I've kept all the other settings just incase there's anything there that might have an impact on the problem.

```
  $('#mimicTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'lip<"mimicSpacer">f<"numUnAck">rt',
    "sScrollY": "365px",
    "aaSorting": [[4,'desc'],[5,'desc']],
    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    "aLengthMenu": [[15, 50, 100, -1], [15, 50, 100, 'All']],
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumns": [
      null,
      { "sWidth": "20%" },
      { "sWidth": "22%" },
      { "sWidth": "9%" },
      { "sWidth": "9%" },
      { "sWidth": "20%" },
      { "sWidth": "20%" }
    ],
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
      $(nRow).attr("id",'alarmNum' + aData[0]);
      return nRow;
    }
  });
```

A `console.log` of the dataTable object shows:
[image: missing row ids]

As you can see, #14 has the row id and also the correct rowStripe class.  #15 (and onwards) doesn't.

**So, why is fnRowCallback not firing each time a row is added, only sometimes?  Maybe there is a better way to add a row ID when a row is added?**

Comment: Is the callback definitely not running? Have you tried logging the value of nRow within the `fnRowCallback` function?

Comment: Hi Phil, fnRowCallback seems to be called multiple times so it's hard to get just 46 rows output to see whats going on.

Comment: users like to look at a jsfiddle if they should answer more complex questions (otherwise it takes to long to analyse for them and they just go on with the next question)

Comment: does each row not already have a unique id - its position within the array?

Comment: @matpol - yes, but if I understand things correctly, I need to use .fnGetNodes() and then .filter() to get the row in order to update it's displayed column data.  Note, the row I need to update may be filtered out and / or on a different page.

Comment: @micha - added at http://live.datatables.net/olovos/10

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the solution:
http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2119/adding-row-attributes-after-fnadddata/p1

For anyone else wanting a quick solution, I did:

```
var addId = $('#mimicTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
  alarmID,
  'col2',
  'col3',
  'col4',
  'col5'
]);

var theNode = $('#mimicTable').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[addId[0]].nTr;
theNode.setAttribute('id','alarmNum' + alarmID);
```

Comment: addId is defined just above.  From the documentation, fnAddData returns an array of integers, representing the list of indexes in aoData that have been added to the table.  As we are only adding one row, then it is returning the index added.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is quite an old thread, but this might help others.
The easiest way I do it to add id attribute to the last added row as soon as I called the data table function `fnAddData` is:

```
$('#table').dataTable().fnAddData( ['col1','col2','col3'] );     

$('#table tr:last').attr('id','col'+row_id);
```

Comment: if the size of data you are adding is larger than the number of rows you display in one page. this won't work.

Comment: This is exactly why i love stackOverflow... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this it worked for me nicely:

```
var newRow = oTable.fnAddData( [ etc..]);
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings(); 
var nTr = oSettings.aoData[ newRow[0] ].nTr;
nTr.id = 'new id';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something unexpected with your code in the jsbin, even if it appears to be working. It initializes with the "browsers" data set. Then it clears. Then it makes a new table with one row. Then it clears. Then it makes a new table with two rows. Then it clears. Then it makes a new table with three rows.

I'd have to get a better sense of the code sample and its end goal (and alas my attention is diverted elsewhere right now) but you should be aware that fnRowCallback SHOULD be the way to do this, and that there are many redundant table constructions and row additions that are going to impact performance as well as flexibility with modifying rendering in the future.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but have a look at the answer I posted.  It works :)  Performance appears to be ok, but I am going to do further tests.

Comment: Have you folded the updated code into the jsbin? I'd be curious to poke around, too. I could help you find any anomalies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DT_RowId when you add new row, and use object instead an array, see below:

```
 $('#mimicTable').dataTable().fnAddData({
            'DT_RowId': alarmID, 0:'col2', 1:'col3', 2:'col4',
            3:'col5', 4:'col6', 5:'col7'
        });
```

Comment: You should always explain your answers instead of just pasting a block of code

Comment: Looked around forever before I saw this snippet which helped me figure out the cryptic error I was getting. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
var MyUniqueID = "tr123"; // this is the uniqueId.
var rowIndex = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([ "column1Data", "column2Data"]);
var row = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnGetNodes(rowIndex);
$(row).attr('id', MyUniqueID);
```